# Scroll down button animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a photography portfolio website, and need to make a scroll down button. I made the scroll button using html and css and tried to use jquery to create an animation where it slowly goes down the page when you click the scroll down button. However, as of right now it just immediately goes down to the second section. However, when I tried to it on codepen, the animation worked.

https://codepen.io/alihaider2018/pen/PQQXLZ (imgs not showing, and changed background to blue so you can see the button better)

```js
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 500, 'linear');
    }); 
});
```

```css
 #section01 a span {
      position: absolute;
      top: 800px;
      left: 50%;
      width: 46px;
      height: 46px;
      margin-left: -23px;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #section01 a span::after {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      content: '';
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      margin: -12px 0 0 -8px;
      border-left: 1px solid #fff;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #section01 a span::before {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      content: '';
      width: 44px;
      height: 44px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
      border-radius: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="Nature.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webpage.css">
    </head>
    <section id="section01" class="demo">
    <body background="lol.jpg" >
      <div id="nav">

      <ul>
        <li><a href="Contact.html"> Contact </a></li>
        <li><a href="AboutMe.html"> About Me </a></li>
        <li><a href="Business.html"> Business </a></li>
        <li><a href="Street.html"> Street </a></li>
        <li><a href="Nature.html"> Nature </a></li>
      </ul>
      <p id="logo"><a href="webpage.html"> Icyportraitsgta </a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="description">
      <a href="#section02"><span>
          </span></a>

    <p class="para"> GTA Portrait photography <br> with your favourite themes </p>
    </div>
    </section>

    <img src="sanafull15.jpeg" class="sana15" alt="sanafull15"> </img>
    <img src="sanafulle.jpeg" class="sanafulle" alt="sanafulle"> </img>
    <img src="qasside.jpeg" class="qasside" alt="qasside"> </img>
    <section id="section02">
    <img src="icysit.jpg" class="icysit" alt="icysit"> </img>
    <img src="ravedited1.jpg" class="rav1" alt="rav1"> </img>
    <img src="qassmoke1.jpeg" class="qas2" alt="qas2"> </img>
    </body>
    </section>
    </html>
```

Comment: putting your jquery script tag outside of the doc type seems wrong, put it in the head

Comment: yea fixed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is a complete invalid mess. I tried to fix it somehow and the following animation work:

**(click on the "section02" link to animate)**

```js
$(function() {
  console.log('ready');
  $('a[href^=#]').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('click');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 500, 'linear');
  });
});
```

```css
#section01 a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 800px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin-left: -23px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section01 a span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -8px;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section01 a span::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border-radius: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body background="lol.jpg">
  <section id="section01" class="demo">
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Contact.html"> Contact </a></li>
        <li><a href="AboutMe.html"> About Me </a></li>
        <li><a href="Business.html"> Business </a></li>
        <li><a href="Street.html"> Street </a></li>
        <li><a href="Nature.html"> Nature </a></li>
      </ul>
      <p id="logo"><a href="webpage.html"> Icyportraitsgta </a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="description">
      <a href="#section02">section02<span>
      </span></a>

      <p class="para"> GTA Portrait photography <br> with your favourite themes </p>
    </div>

    <img src="sanafull15.jpeg" class="sana15" alt="sanafull15">
    <img src="sanafulle.jpeg" class="sanafulle" alt="sanafulle">
    <img src="qasside.jpeg" class="qasside" alt="qasside">
  </section>


  <section id="section02">

    <img src="icysit.jpg" class="icysit" alt="icysit">
    <img src="ravedited1.jpg" class="rav1" alt="rav1">
    <img src="qassmoke1.jpeg" class="qas2" alt="qas2">
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```